In shell, do variable expansions occur inside command substitution?
I know variable expansions happen before command substitution, but I am still not sure about this.
Given "name" is a shell variable with value "abc", when I run echo $(echo $name), which of the following is correct:

The variable is firstly expanded (in the "outer" level). The code becomes echo $(echo abc), then the command substitution happens.
name is not directly expanded. Instead, the variable expansion happens inside $(echo $name).

I tried the following.
$ name=abc
$ echo $(name=xyz; echo $name)

The code indeed outputs xyz, which suggests that the expansion of $name happens inside $(). That seems to contradict the rule that variable expansion happens because command substitution.
I do find a similar question order of expansion between variable expansion and command substitution, but it was 13 years ago, and that one does not have a convincing answer yet.

"The rule that variable expansion happens because command substitution" -- What rule would that be? Variable expansion happens before a command is executed. The outer echo prints the result of the command substitution, so that has to be executed first. Since $name could be modified within the $() (like in your case), expanding it before executing the substitution would be faulty. In the end, I wouldn't overthink the "why". It's more useful this way, so that's good.

"but it was 13 years ago" - we had one major Bash version in the mean time. Now imagine such a fundamental thing would change between versions and break shell scripts everywhere in the world. Sysadmins might actually physically leave their desks to go to the lynching...

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions   """The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion."""

In the EXPANSION section of man bash:
       The  order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter
       and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and  command  substitution
       (done   in  a  left-to-right  fashion);  word  splitting;  and  pathname
       expansion.

In the Command Substitution section:
       When using the $(command) form,  all  characters  between
       the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

So the command in $() is left untouched (there is no expansion in the command substitution), until it is executed in a sub-shell.
Then, the same order of expansion is done (brace, tilde, param & var, arithmetic, command substitution, word splitting, pathname).
We can therefore say with certainty that the result will be:
$ name=abc
$ echo $(name=xyz; echo $name)
xyz

